# apple mdm: DeviceInformation command

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I want to execute the `DeviceInformation` command on iOS devices. So far I have a configuration profile with mdm payload installed on the device.

What are the steps involved in executing this command on the device and getting the attributes back to the mdm server?

The objective is to do this with no user interaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the device is registered with your MDM system, the steps are 1. ping the device using APNS, 2. the device requests your check-in URL, 3. in response, you give it the DeviceInformation command, 4. the device checks back in with the response to the DeviceInformation command.